# Self Refresh a database every given time

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

**Background**

I'm using PHP+SQL to update a database every 60 seconds (Via sql queries). However, to do this, I do it from the browser, but there's a problem: *Every time I get into the page, it updates the database. It also happens when I'm into the page already, and I just Refresh the page.* **I don't want that.**

What I'm looking for, is to get into the page, and that's it, just get into the page. I'm looking for ways to do this, but the only things I've been found right now (and the main reason I'm asking you) is:

Self Refresh the page with Javascript with this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); 
}, 60000);
</script>
```

And by HTML Meta.

Unfortunately, doing both of them so, sends the query to the database (when it's not intended that way. The intended way is to do it every 60 seconds).

Is even possible what I'm looking for? If so, what do I need to do to get it working? Thanks in advance for your answers. I hope I didn't give you any wrong information.

Edit:

I forgot to add something important. I'm looking for this since while the ideal case is the page to be open at all times, there's more to do (like register users to name something).

First, I want to thank you for all your time. Since I didn't understand the AJAX code (I'm still a novice on this) I did some research. Somehow that research made me see I was wrong all the time. What I was looking to do can be done it on the server side and not on the client side.

So, what I did is to create an Even.

```
EVENT `updtable` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE 
DO 
UPDATE son SET time = time -1 WHERE time !=0;
```

And that's it. It does exactly what I want to do. I think I just messed up explaining or I'm just dumb enough to realize. I'm both thankful for your answers and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: cant you send a post or get variable for refreshing the database and database only refresh when these variable are set?

Comment: I really can't send a Post since the page needs to get opened from one way or another, and I don't think I can really get a variable set since there will be other things activities to do (I actually forgot to add that)

Comment: Well, you can try it with the Ajax request..! The only way to effectively prevent a db reset on page refresh would be to do it server-side using `$_SESSION` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using AJAX request to your php page!

```
// Worker script for database update.
// Called every 60 seconds
(function worker() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'databaseupdate.php', //Put the file which updates the database
        data: {tag: "check"}, // Send post variable to prevent direct access
        success: function(data) {
            // Put anything here which you want done after the db update is done
        },
        complete: function() {
            // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
            setTimeout(worker, 60000);
        }
    });
})();
```

Well, in this case, you wouldn't require to refresh the whole page again.

Problem here: It WILL update db on manual page refresh.

Solution:
On your php page, put a session variable, which will log the time of the last entry. Then simply put a check if `(Current Time) - (Last update Time) >=60` & you're good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't understand AJAX, so while I was looking for how to work with AJAX, PHP and SQL, I found an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to post something to a page and that page reset the database only if the post variable is set, but considering
that you don't want your database to reset when you refresh the page, I suggest Ajax post, not a regular post, because in regular post
when you try to refresh the page, browser asks for sending the post again or not.

So, I suggest something like this :

```
<script src='path/to/jquery.js'></script>
<script>
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $.post('reset.php', {reset: 1}, function(e) {
            if (e)
                document.location.reload(true);
        });
    }, 6000);
</script>
```

and your **reset.php** :

```
<?php
if ($_POST['reset']) {
    //Do whatever you do to reset your database
}
die(1);
?>
```

Comment: +1 - nice, this way the database doesn't reset on regular refresh

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you, but I tried this one, it still reset on regular access/refresh. I will try the Ajax Post to check if it can solve my problem.